# DataBinding of a UserControl via ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, controltemplate

I'm playing around with the Infragistics xamDataGrid.
I'd like to display in a "Field" (= Cell) a custom UserControl and have for it the Field's DataContext. Somehow the DataContext is always null :-)

Here is the XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="MyTestUserControl" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
          <myUC:MyTestUserControl
              DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                    Path=Value}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
  <Style x:Key="TextBoxField" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
          <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                  Path=Value}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The DataContext for the TextBoxField works fine, but the DataContext for the MyUserControl doesn't.

Some more XAML where I define the Fields:

```
<igDP:UnboundField BindingPath="SimpleTestStringToDisplay" Label="UnboundField">
  <igDP:Field.Settings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource TextBoxField}" />
  </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:UnboundField>

<igDP:UnboundField BindingPath="MyUserControlViewModel"
                   Label="UnboundField (UserControl)">
  <igDP:Field.Settings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource MyTestUserControl}" />
  </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:UnboundField>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Cheers,
Joseph

EDIT: 
I also tried something like this, without success:

```
  <myUC:MyUserControl DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your test project above does not have the same bindings, it does in the templates but not on the 
`<igDP:UnboundField>`

try it using the same bindings and see if you still dont get a data context, then at least the experiment will be valid (isolated). maybe the issue is with your view model binding, try the follwing code -

```
<igDP:UnboundField BindingPath="MyUserControlViewModel" Label="UnboundField" >
  <igDP:Field.Settings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource TextBoxField}" />
  </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:UnboundField>

<igDP:UnboundField BindingPath="MyUserControlViewModel" Label="UnboundField (UserControl)">
  <igDP:Field.Settings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource MyTestUserControl}" />
  </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:UnboundField>
```

if you do this do both the templates not get their data context?. put a [debugConverter (method 2)](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html) on your binding in the template, to make sure youre binding is happening.

By the way, what binding failure messages are you getting in your output window?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually didn't have to put anything in the UserControl.. it'll just "inherit" the DataContext from the UnboundField if declared correctly there ;-)